# Параметры query_posts

Tags: php, wordpress

Использую следующий код, чтобы выводить посты из custom post type

```
query_posts(
    array(
    'post_type'      => 'success-stories',
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'post_id',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
   )
);
```

Задано произвольное поле post_id, для того чтобы была возможность ручной сортировки постов (в нужном порядке). Но также нужно, чтобы выводились и те посты, у которых этот параметр не задан. Подскажите, что нужно изменить в параметрах запроса?

Answer (score 0):

Запрос надо делать по `OR`, выбирая как те записи, где `post_id` не определен, так и те, где он больше нуля:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'success-stories',
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
         'key' => 'post_id',
         'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
         'value' => ''
        ),
        array(
         'key' => 'post_id',
         'compare' => '>',
         'value' => '0'
        )
    ),
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'          => 'ASC'
    );

query_posts($args);
```

Comment: В таком случае выводит все посты, кроме тех где post_id заполнено

Comment: `'relation' => 'OR'` не пропустили?

Comment: Нет, пробовал значение менять даже на другое (AND)

Comment: а какие значения принимает post_id? Больше нуля все, например?

Comment: Да, любое число больше 0

Comment: Накатал у себя тест http://test.kagg.eu/so635358/ - работает. Поправил ответ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54824/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-).

Answer (score 0):

`query_posts` использовать небезопасно.

Используйте `get_posts`, `pre_get_posts` или `WP_Query`.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

> `'meta_key' => 'post_id'`

В названиях нельзя использовать "post_id". Это зарезервированный (служебный) термин.

Comment: его нет в https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms

Comment: это имя глобальной переменной https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta И вообще плохой тон кодинга - давать своим сущностям названия используемых. Нужно сразу привыкать хотя бы свои уник префиксы/суффиксы писать.

Comment: Это имя локальной переменной (аргумента) указанной функции, не более того. В списке глобальных переменных https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables `$post_id` тоже отсутствует.  Собственно, подтверждением служит то, что мой тест http://test.kagg.eu/so635358/ работает. А насчет того, что не очень хорошо имя `post_id` в своих произвольных полях указывать - согласен.