# Вывод названия категории в шаблоне page.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть custom post type и custom taxonomy. Есть страница page.php и на ней выводятся посты из этой таксономии.

```
query_posts(
  array(
    'post_type'      => 'success-stories',
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
   )
);
```

Дальше через цикл выводятся превью постов. И вот тут бы хотелось вставить название категории к каждому посту. Через `single_cat_title()` не выводится ничего. Знает ли кто-то как это правильно сделать именно в шаблоне `page.php`?

Comment: Да нельзя же использовать query_posts. Уже ж [показывал как надо](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/635434).

Comment: Дело в том, что тема не моя, я только вношу некоторые правки. А она полностью сделана на query_posts. Полностью переделывать неохота. Там на самом деле много чего можно было бы изменить и сделать по другому, но имеем то что имеем. SeVlad, из-за этого может не работать single_cat_title()?

Comment: Значит надо выкинуть эту тему. Уже ясно что он ибо древнючая либо написано криворучкой. В любом случае небезопасна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`single_cat_title()` можно использовать только за пределами Цикла WordPress.

Для получения в цикле WordPress массива категорий, относящихся к текущему посту, надо использовать `get_the_category()`.

Для получения в цикле WordPress массива терминов таксономии, относящихся к текущему посту, надо использовать `get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy )`.

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего, надо исправить запрос на корректный (не через query_posts):

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'paged' => $paged,
   'post_type' => 'success-stories'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  $query->the_post();        
  the_title(); // выведем заголовок поста
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Для вывода кастомных таксономий служит функция single_term_title().
https://wp-kama.ru/function/single_term_title

Comment: пропустили запятую после 'posts_per_page' => -1. Добавил под title single_term_title(), но кроме тайтлов ничего не выводит

Comment: поправил код.
В вопросе было: хотелось вставить название категории к каждому посту.
Тайтл - это и есть название (заголовок) категории. 
А дальше надо смотреть, с какими параметрами запустить функцию single_term_title () либо внутри цикла выдергивать те переменные, которые нужны.